# Given a set of surrounding colors, how to find a good color template?

Tags: background, color-theory, critique

This is a map of topics the I cover in my project. The topics are segmented in different stages, and I would like to have your advice on how to color the segments. I check the color wheel to find a suitable color template, but I don't see one really fit with the yellow sky and blue water. In the end I set them while altogether. I satisfy with this, but since I want to learn more about color theory, if you can recommend a good template that would be nice.

[image]

<sub>([SVG file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AooXkYrfSXq4g99Ad4FxA6jU80Dl1g?e=OFEb83))</sub>

For some background, *The Sphere* and *Theory of perspective* are two of my projects. The latter is the underlying theoretical framework for the former, while the former is the application of the latter. Most of my audience only need to know the former, so I think the iceberg analogy is suitable. Yes I'm aware that [7/8ths of an iceberg is below the water line](https://www.navcen.uscg.gov/?pageName=iipHowMuchOfAnIcebergIsBelowTheWater), but I guess as long as the analogy serves the purpose it doesn't matter much.

Comment: oooh... *iceberg* ...I missed that previously.. darn light colored links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have anything against the colors you have chosen. The iceberg being all white is actually quite fitting for a diagram of this kind in my opinion. Often "less is more". Nonetheless, I've given it a go and made a more colorful version for your inspiration.

[image]

(I didn't have the fonts installed so you'll have to live with Arial.)

I haven't used any specific color theory or even looked at a color wheel. Since your drawing depicts a (very stylized) realistic setting, you don't really have a free choice of colors. A red iceberg and yellow water just wouldn't look right. The colors need to be somewhat realistic.

I know that you wanted to keep the color of the sky and the water as they were, but choosing colors is much about balancing the whole, so I've taken the liberty of changing all the colors.

- The iceberg is kept in light cyan nuances which you often see in ice.
- The water is a medium deep blue.
- The part of the iceberg that is under water is a dark, slightly cyan blue which shows how it's in shadow.
- The sky is a gradient from yellow to orange red, which is both what you will see in nature, and in contrast to the other colors.
- The texts have all been softened a bit by choosing other colors than black:

  - The header and the small labels has the same color as the fill of the underwater part of the iceberg.
  - The labels under water had to be inverted to white to be visible, which gives the diagram some life. They could perhaps be bright cyan to show more coherence with the top part of the iceberg.
  - The big labels above sea level are orange red to blend in a little more with the background while still being visible.
  - The big label in the bottom is white to stand out in the dark water.